# .htaccess Redirect IP address to HTTPS domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect my sites ip address to its https domain but I am getting the error

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 123.123.123.123 
(for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

This is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`https` is an certificate you have to buy for your domain. So it will secure your site.

As well as in google there is lot of answer about [**Force Redirect `http` to `https`**.](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-ssl-using-the-htaccess-file)
But it wont work at all. Cz you cant force redirect. It will load your site with **`Malitious` Warning**.

> So its better to buy [**SSL Certificate**](https://www.instantssl.com/)

Force redirect `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Or allow the IP

```
   #Allow List

    order allow,deny
    allow from 123.123.123.123 #specify a specific address
    allow from 123.123.123.123/30 #specify a subnet range
    allow from 123.123.* #specify an IP address wildcard
    deny from all
```

Comment: my domain already has https. I only get the error when trying to redirect the ip address to it

Comment: Follow the link ther is some .htaccess

Comment: I didn't post my full htaccess file in my question. I already redirect to the https:// version when a user visits the http:// version without any problems. The htaccess you posted didn't work for when a user types my sites ip address